# view bounds change after disposing UIActivityViewController on iOS 7 in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I'm having a strange behavior when using a UIActivityViewController:

I have a UIViewController (768x704) with a share button. When I tap the share button, a UIActivityView opens. After closing the ActivityView, my navigation bar (or the view controller itself) changes its size.

Here's the code:

```
NSLog(@"Old bounds: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:shareText] applicationActivities:nil];
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
    NSLog(@"New bounds: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
}];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The output:

```
Old Bounds: {{0, 0}, {768, 704}}
New Bounds: {{0, 0}, {768, 724}}
```

Seems to be the height of the status bar.

This only happens with iOS 7, on iPad in landscape mode. Any other scenario works well - without any glitches.

Could this be a bug in iOS7? Or is it just me, doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [UIActivityViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011976-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5) UIActivityViews should be presented in popovers:

> **Discussion**
>
> [...] On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover. On other devices, you must present it modally.

When I put my `UIActivityViewController` in a popover, my problem seems to be fixed.

Lesson learned: I should more often read Class References ;)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 your controller usually is overlapped bu navigation bar.
Try adding this method to your controller:

```
- (UIRectEdge) edgesForExtendedLayout
{
    return UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Your navigation controller is also overlapped by satatusbar.
recently using system controller cause enormous amount of undocumented behavior.

P.S. Why are you presenting activity controller from self.navigationController instead of presenting it from self?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `edgesForExendedLayout` doesn't work either, sadly. Presenting it from self.navigationController was just to test if this has anything to do with my problem - I changed this in my question.